# Should I add an online demo link?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

I'm a member for a year now and actively answering questions in [php](/questions/tagged/php) and [regex](/questions/tagged/regex).
That said, I saw some members adding online demo's of their solutions to their answers and thought it was pretty good to do so too.

I noticed some advantages:

- **More upvotes:** People have instant results and could see that it works as expected and wouldn't need to copy/paste to test the code.
- **More explanation:** With regex questions, there is [regex101](http://regex101.com/) which provides explanation to the regex code, and it's easy to "track" since they are highlighted with nice colors.
- **Multi versions:** For example [3v4l](http://3v4l.org) one can easily show how compatible his code is with older versions of PHP.

Recently I noticed a downside, the online demo is sometimes down and inaccessible. That said, what if the online demo service would stop ? I would have ~200 answers with dead links.

So my final question is: Should I add an online demo link to my answers?

<sub>**PS:** Assuming that I explain my code in my answer too.</sub>

Comment: Add it only **in addition** to the code in your answer, not instead of the code.

Comment: ^ That's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: I think it's pretty clear by now that code should be included with demos and if you have to pick code or demo, pick code. Just for the reasons you mentioned. Links in most cases will die over time, regardless. Should be not include demos at all because of this? I don't think so. Demo's can be extremely helpful, and at times having one available determines whether or not I even try to help...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whenever you feel that it would help increase the usefulness of your answer, feel free to add links to services like JSFiddle, Ideone, and others.

## But...

Always, always include the code (and optionally output, if important) in your post.

Answer (score 2):

I like to provide links to online demos. If you don't have the code as well in the answer (sometimes it's too long or [for example the license does not fit](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#SourceCodeInDocumentation) - as the example is treated as code and CC licenses do not do well with code) you should provide some backup location next to the codepad (for example github gist).

Also there are codepads and codepads - some are totally unstable and loose all the code from time to time (even quite quickly), others are rock solid. As most are free, you don't know upfront :) so keep some backup, I made the mistake with larger code some time ago, nowadays I often leave a gist as well.

For an answer, it's normally okay when you provide some description and pseudo-code and/or the code of the most important part so that an explanation is given and reading code can be helpful.

---

Links:

- [Can I use snippets of GPL-covered source code within documentation that is licensed under some license that is incompatible with the GPL?](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#SourceCodeInDocumentation)